# Mongoid not playing nicely with factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mongoid, testunit

Moingoid doesn't seem to be setting embedded relationships persistently during my tests. In my user model I have:

```
  def vote_on(bill, value)
    if my_groups = self.groups
      my_groups.each do |g|
        bill.votes.create(:value => value, :user_id => self.id, :group_id => g.id)
        # result only with factories: bill.votes.first.group = nil
        # and bill.votes.first.user = nil !!
        # self.id and g.id have good values during the test, they just aren't persisting
      end
    else
      raise "no groups for this user" # #{self.full_name}"
    end
  end
```

Other helpful code might be:

```
## bill model
class Bill
   embeds_many :votes

## vote model

class Vote
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :value, :type => Symbol # can be :aye, :nay, :abstain
  #field :group_type, :type => Integer

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  embedded_in :bill

end

## test

  test "descriptive tally should work" do
    user1 = Factory.build(:user)
    b = Factory.build(:bill)
    user1.vote_on(b, :aye) # nil values created here!
    tally = b.descriptive_tally
    assert_not_nil tally
  end

## bill factory

Factory.define :bill do |f|
  f.bill_html "just the facts"
  ...
  f.state "Introduced"
  f.text_updated_on DateTime.parse("2011-06-16 00:00:00 Z")
  f.text_word_count 2356
  f.votes
end

## user factory

Factory.define :user do |u|
   u.email      'user@domain.com'
   u.name       'user'
   u.roles_mask 1
   u.password   "secret"
   u.password_confirmation "secret"
   u.groups {[Factory.build(:group, {:name => 'foreign', :type => :custom})]}
end
```

This is a real head-scratcher for me. Perhaps this is a bug I need to better explore and submit. My first guess is that I am just missing something simple in my factories or test setup. This code works well on development. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the error is the same if I use: bill.votes << Vote.new(:value => value, :user_id => self.id, :group_id => g.id)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are issues with most factory gems and Mongoid. I seem to recall having a lot of issues trying to use both Factory Girl and Machinist.

[Fabrication](http://fabricationgem.org/) seems to be the current recommended standard for doing object generation in tests with Mongoid. It's worked perfectly for us on all our Mongoid projects.

Comment: I started playing with fabrications. I think this is the way I need to go. Wow, the world changes so fast . . .