# FactoryGirl creates incomplete model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, factory-bot, rspec-rails

Assume that I have a city model where:

```
class city
  field :full_name, type: String # San Francisco, CA, United States
  field :_id, type: String, overwrite: true, default: ->{ full_name }
end
```

Assume that I have a factory defined in **/spec/factories/cities.rb**:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :city do
    full_name 'San Francisco, CA, United States'
  end
end
```

Running the following code in one of the specs:

```
city_attrs = { full_name: 'San Francisco, CA, United States' }
City.create! city_attrs
=> #<City _id: San Francisco, CA, United States, full_name: "San Francisco, CA, United States">

FactoryGirl.create(:city)
=> #<City _id: , full_name: "San Francisco, CA, United States">
```

How do I fix this without adding the following code to the **/spec/factories/cities.rb**?

```
before(:create) do |city, evaluator|
  city.id = city.full_name
end
```

**EDIT**
the solution is to stop using `FactoryGirl` and use [`Fabrication`](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) instead as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6449928/1769515)

Comment: Why not just add that code?

Comment: in some cases the model will have call back procedures that will alter a lot of it's attributes... i want the `FactoryGirl` create to follow this call backs instead of providing these kind of call backs in the `before(:create)`

Comment: if you are not using `ActiveRecord` could you please at least mention the database adapter you are using?

Comment: did you try calling [apply_defaults](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/fields.rb#L91) ?

Comment: `apply_defaults` didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the initialization of the model used by FactoryGirl:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  trait :explicit_initialize do
    initialize_with { new(attributes) }
  end

  factory :city, traits: [:explicit_initialize] do
    full_name 'San Francisco, CA, United States'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Like explain on documentation, all default define in lambda are lazy. So you need pre_process it :

> When defining a default value as a proc, Mongoid will apply the default after all other attributes are set. If you want this to happen before the other attributes, set pre_processed: true.

```
class city
  field :full_name, type: String # San Francisco, CA, United States
  field :_id, type: String, overwrite: true, pre_processed: true, default: ->{ full_name }
end
```